# how to echo an input type in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code, what I want to do is to be able to have a back button in the script, so that the user will not be clicking on the back button on the web browser everytime he forgets to input something that is mandatory:
But I get the parse error again,what should be the correct one?

```
   if(!isset($_POST['fname'])||trim($_POST['fname'])==""){die("Error:Enter Firstname!");     echo "<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include double quotes inside a double quoted string without escaping them:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Back\" onClick=\"history.go(-1);return true;\">"
```

Or since you have no variable to parse:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_POST['fname']) || trim($_POST['fname']) == "") {
  echo "Error:Enter Firstname!";     
  echo '<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">';
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your quotes for one thing --

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Back\" onClick=\"history.go(-1);return true;\">"
```

(or use single quotes as above)